# Clear Magento cache based on key pattern

Tags: magento

Is there a way in magento to clear specific parts of the cache whihc begin with a specific cache key.

I would like to clear everything in my module that have a key that begin with:

**mynamespace_mymodule_**

so the following will be clear from cache:

```
mynamespace_mymodule_asdaqasd

mynamespace_mymodule_qeqweq

mynamespace_mymodule_poipoi
```

etc
etc

Comment: along with cache key, which is the unique identifier of cache, there are cache tags, which are created for the very purpose you want to achieve - to group cache under one logical namespace. So just assign appropriate **cache tag** to your cache (eg *mynamespace_mymodule*) and you'll be able to clear all cache tagged with your tag easily

Comment: I will second Slayer's comment - the cache tags are there for this very reason. You should, through `cache.xml` then add your module to the cache grid in System > Cache Management.

Comment: @slayer you should add this as an answer.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, @ben - I should have done it right away

Answer (score 3):

Magento's caching system allows you to assign both **cache key** (unique id) and **cache tags** while saving your cache. Look at `Mage_Core_Model_Cache::save` [method](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.html#save) - 3d argument is **cache tags** array.

By assigning *cache tags* you'll have ability to remove all cache which is tagged with *your cache tag* at once. [`Mage_Core_Model_Cache::clean`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.html#clean) methid will take array of cache tags as an argument.

Comment: In addition, see this article, paying special attention to the comments. http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/improving-the-file-cache-backend/